# How to write "o" with upper-line in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

How do you write a character "o" with upper-line in Ubuntu? Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

If you haven't already done this, configure a compose key by going into System Settings > Keyboard > Layout Settings > Options... > Compose key position. (I've set mine to Right Alt.)

Then, all you have to do is type <kbd>*Compose* + -</kbd>, then <kbd>o</kbd> and you'll get an ō. This works for the other letters, too, as well as several different types of accents. For example, <kbd>'</kbd> instead of <kbd>-</kbd> will give you an acute accent, <kbd>`</kbd> will give you a grave accent, <kbd>,</kbd> will give you a cedilla, <kbd>^</kbd> a circumflex, and <kbd>"</kbd>, an umlaut.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean:

Ō

ō

In Ubuntu, we have an application similar to Windows' Character Map called...well, Character Map. Go into it and look around at what all you can do :)

As for a keyboard shortcut, there are keyboard shortcuts listed on the character map. :)

Answer (score 0):

In vim, you can do it with digraphs.

E.g., in insert mode ō is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then `o-` (press <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> at the same time, then type `o-`)

Ō is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and `O-`.

See [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html) for a more complete explanation.